# filter sheets google analytics plugin

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, add-in

I have implemented the Google Analytics Add-on to my Google Sheets Account.. I'm building a Dashboard for the company I work for, working in E-commerce... The issue I'm having has to do with filters (I believe)... One of the metrics we look at on a weekly basis is performance by channel (i.e. Organic, Email, Display, Direct etc..) I don't know how to create reports that spit out the data for each specific medium.. The idea is so I build this dashboard so it updates dynamically(obviously) but unless I figure out how to filter metrics like revenue and traffic by medium I'm unable to do that...

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

**metric**     ga:transactionRevenue 
**dimension**  ga:sourceMedium
**sort**      -ga:transactionRevenue

[Screen Shot of full query Source / Medium Revenue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLpNO.png)